# Docker-compose throwing error

Tags: docker, vagrant, yaml, docker-compose

Hello guys I'm trying to get my vagrant up but the docker keeps on throwing an error which is given below :

```
Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent. Are you in the right directory
```

The file is present at the root of my project. It was all working well but it just started to throw an error. Can somebody tell me what is it that I have done due to which I'm getting this error

Comment: The Vagrantfile and docker-compose.yml would be useful along with their relative locations.

Comment: @JonStirling: They are both at the root

Comment: Okay, so now if you could include the content of those files in your question, maybe somebody can help you with an answer.

Comment: @JonStirling: You are right about that. But the thing is I do not have access to that file since those things are present on a remote server

Comment: What? Then how are you running it if you don't have access to it...

Comment: @JonStirling: sorry for the misunderstanding. To be precise I have the permission to execute it but not read and write

Comment: Then you'll have to bring it up with your sysadmin.

Comment: @JonStirling: I have emailed them. Let's see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I had this error but it was due to vagrant. If you are running vagrant then first of all enter into your vagrant machine using :

`vagrant ssh command`

and try to find the file over there. If you don't have it over there then this is the problem. That file is not being loaded over here because of which you are getting this error.

My error was coming because vagrant was not mounting the nfs partition because of which the whole project was not loading in the vagrant machine and after that, the docker command was being run. Since the project was not being loaded docker command was not able to find the required file.

If this is your problem try to mount your nfs partition first.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
docker-compose -f rootoftheprojectpath/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Check read permissions, typos, etc. Also check that your file is not empty

Regards